# Como definir a url para uma rota no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, route

Estou utilizando Laravel 5.4 e controllers no padrão Restful.

Configurei o arquivo de rotas da seguinte forma:

```
Route::resource('entryRegistry', 'EntryRegistryController');
```

Na view:

```
{{ route('entryRegistry.create') }}
```

Na Controller:

```
public function create() { }
```

Com isto, a url da minha pagina ficou:

```
/entryRegistry/create
```

Como faço para alterar a url que faz referencia a rota da funcion create ?

Eu quero alterar o `entryregistry/create` para `registro-ponto/criar`, sem alterar a estrutura da controler e também sem alterar o nome da function e da controller em questão.

Comment: O que exatamente você quer alterar?

Comment: Quero alterar o texto que aparece na url do navegador

Comment: mas qual parte? o início da uri é controlada pelo primeiro argumento passado para a rota `'entryRegistry'`. É essa parte que te incomoda ou o `create`, ou a url como um todo?

Comment: eu quero alterar o entryregistry/create para registro-ponto/criar, sem alterar a estrutura da controler e também sem alterar o nome da function e da controller em questão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia em se utilizar um `Route::resource` é padronizar todas as rotas de determinado recurso seguindo uma convenção que [está documentada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) aqui:

```
| Verb      | URI                  | Action  | Route Name     |
|-----------|----------------------|---------|----------------|
| GET       | /photos              | index   | photos.index   |
| GET       | /photos/create       | create  | photos.create  |
| POST      | /photos              | store   | photos.store   |
| GET       | /photos/{photo}      | show    | photos.show    |
| GET       | /photos/{photo}/edit | edit    | photos.edit    |
| PUT/PATCH | /photos/{photo}      | update  | photos.update  |
| DELETE    | /photos/{photo}      | destroy | photos.destroy |
```

Você pode mudar isso redefinindo suas rotas sem usar o `Route::resource`, dessa forma você terá mais controle:

```
Route::get('registro-ponto/criar', 'EntryRegistryController@create')
    ->name('entryRegistry.create');

// Se quiser, pode declarar só a rota de create fora do resource

Route::resource('entryRegistry', 'EntryRegistryController', ['except' => ['create']]);
```

Tenha em mente que fazer isso quebra o RESTful das rotas.

Leia mais sobre como definir suas rotas e sobre *Resource Controllers* na documentação do Laravel:

- [*Routing*<sup>en</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing)
- [*Resource Controllers*<sup>en</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers)